# Using pattern matching with Specs2 and Play in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have a simple problem with Scala/Play 2.0 and Specs.

This is my test

```
"Server" should {
"return a valid item with appropriate content type or a 404" in {
        val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/item/1"))
        status(result) match {
            case 200 => contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
            case 404 => true
            case _ => throw new Exception("The Item server did not return either a 200 application/json or a 404")
        }
        //false   --> It only compiles if I add this line!
 }
}
}
```

This doesnt compile because of the following:

```
 No implicit view available from Any => org.specs2.execute.Result.
[error]     "return a valid item with appropriate content type or a 404" in {
[error]                                                                  ^
[error] one error found
```

So Im thinking status(result) match is evaluating to Any hence the error. How should I specify that its result type is Result given that I am having a default case with a false return value?

Comment: You can add `must not(throwA[MyException])` at the end. I would stick with some custom exception, not general Exception.

Comment: Im having trouble adding at the end, I tried it adding it after match ie -> status(result)match{...} must not (throwA[Exception]) and now Im getting: ';' expected but identifier found.
[error]       } must not (throwA[Exception])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to add one precision to Andrea's answer.

Each branch indeed needs to give rise to a common type that can be converted to `Result`. The first branch type is `MatchResult[Option[String]]` and the second and third types are of type `Result`.

There is a way to avoid the type annotation by using a `MatchResult` instead of a `Result`. `ok` and `ko` are 2 `MatchResult`s, equivalent to `success` and `failure`, and can be used here:

```
"return a valid item with appropriate content type or a 404" in {
  val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/item/1"))
  status(result) match {
    case 200 => contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
    case 404 => ok
    case _   => ko("The Item server did not return ... or a 404")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this sorts the problem for good, changing the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

You should ensure that each branch of the match results something convertible to specs2 `Result`. So, instead of `true` you can use `success` and instead of `throw new Exception("...")` use `failure("...")`.

**Edit:**
It seems you also have to help Scalac out a bit. Add parentheses around the match and ascribe the type like this:

```
import org.specs2.execute.Result

"return a valid item with appropriate content type or a 404" in {
    val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(GET, "/item/1"))
    (status(result) match {
      case 200 => contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
      case 404 => success
      case _ => failure("The Item server did not return either a 200 application/json or a 404")
    }): Result
 }
```

Comment: I wrote it that way and now Im getting: No implicit view available from ScalaObject => org.specs2.execute.Result

Comment: Thanks, worked great. I thought the scalac type-inference would do it alone but alas, thanks a lot!